# Cannot create multiple ckeditor instances ("default" is already registered)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a page (using kendo-ui if that makes any difference) that has three text areas that need to be made into editors. The problem is that I can only create one ckeditor instance. No matter how I try to create new instances, I get this error:

```
uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.add] The resource name "default" is already registered.
```

Google-ing for that specific error message only lands me one result that doesn't really tell me anything about it.

This is what I have tried so far after searching various issues like mine on Stack Overflow:

--Deleting instances of the editor if they are not being used /are hidden

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['createText'];
if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
$('#editTemplate').ckeditor();
```

--creating all the instances in document ready

```
    $('#createText').ckeditor();
    $('#editText').ckeditor();
    $('#editTemplate').ckeditor();
```

--using class names instead of jquery to spawn the instances

```
    <textarea id="editText" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
```

--not using jquery and creating instances with

```
CKEDITOR.replace('createText');
```

No matter what I do I cannot create more than one editor, I just get "The resource name "default" is already registered."  I've even tried to manually remove default from resourceManager, but there is no

```
CKEDITOR.resourceManager.remove
```

At this point I am completely out of ideas, and nothing I search for seems to address this exact issue. I am using ckeditor version 4.4.4

Comment: Do all the items have unique ID values? I do this all the time like this: `CKEDITOR.replace('idval1'); CKEDITOR.replace('idval2');` etc.

Comment: They all have unique IDs. CreateText, EditText and EditTemplate.

Comment: I had similar problem, but solved with each-loop, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696695/adding-multiple-ckeditor-instances-in-jquery).

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: The CKEditor will automatically convert every `textarea` having class `class="ckeditor"` into an editor, if they are initially in the DOM. So if you call `$('#editText').ckeditor();` you will apply it twice (But the message then should be `Uncaught The editor instance "editText" is already attached to the provided element.`. Beside that in you question you destroy `createText`   but then you try to create `editTemplate` after that, is that a typo?

Comment: When using class names, I removed the calls like $('#editText').ckeditor();.  The other one wasn't a typo. For that example I already created the instance for createText, but wanted to create a different instance, editTemplate.

Comment: Mate, do you get this error after updating the CKEditor library, in Drupal? Check [this solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/2294299).

Comment: @skobaljic I'm not using drupal. Funny thing, that page was the only thing I could find about that error. Hmm. I will check to see if it is a plugin issue

Comment: They say it is the path error for some of plugins (for image plugin I guess). You probably do not have all the resources, try to re-install the CKEditor. It may be you updated the core to new version, but plugins are old (not compatible with core).

Comment: I think that may have something to do with it! I figured if it was loading some plugin incorrectly, it would be in my config.js. I commented out most of it and now it is working. Thanks for helping me figure out where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to skobaljic I was able to determine where the problem came from. In my config.js I had this block:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('default', [
// Block Styles
{ name: 'Subtitle', element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': '#aaa', 'font-style': 'italic' } },
// Object Styles
{ name: 'Small', element: 'font', attributes: { size: 3 } }
]);
```

commenting that block out the editors all work as expected. I think in order to add those styles into each editor instance I'll have to use separate config files or something, but that goes out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

just had this problem myself, here's a solution I found:
In config.js:

```
// For some reason having multiple on one page runs this config function twice, causing an error
//  Therefore we need to check if this already exists first
//  It should now work with multiple on one page
if (!CKEDITOR.stylesSet.registered['default']) {
    CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('default', [
        ...,
    ]);
}

config.stylesSet = 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found is that if you have the ckeditor class attached to the text area it fails. So get that `class="ckeditor"` out of there.

This works:
http://jsfiddle.net/qahohgrf/

This gives errors: http://jsfiddle.net/4rcgy7wa/